# Change content on list click rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a modal composed of:
- A list of steps at the left
- A content box on the right

**I need to be able to click on the steps on the left and the content changes on the right with the corresponding step description.**

**The markup for showing the steps on the left and content on the right:**

```
 <div class="uk-width-1-3">
   <ul class="pill-steps">
      <% @pill.steps.each_with_index do |step, index| %>
        <li class="pill-step"><span class="pill-number"><%= index + 1%></span><%= step.name %></li>
      <% end %>
   </ul>
 </div>
 <div class="uk-width-2-3 uk-padding-large pill-content">
   <% if @pill.steps.any? %>
    <% @pill.steps.each_with_index do |step, index| %>
       <div id="<%= @pill.id %>" class="pill">
         <h2><%= @pill.steps.first.name %></h2>
         <p><%= @pill.steps.first.desc %></p>
       </div>
    <% end %>
   <% end %>
 </div>
```

**The js to click on the step on the left and showing the content in the right:**

```
  <script>
    $(".pill-step").click(function() {
      $(".pill-content").html("<h2><%= step.name %></h2><p><%= step.desc %></p>");
    });
  </script>
```

I don't know where to put the JS or how to make it dynamic :(
Basically, I want the user to click on the step in the left and show the corresponding `step.description` and **step.title** on the right.

Any ideas on how to achieve this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There are probably a few ways to approach this, but the simplest is probably to initially give all of the `.pill` a class to hide them, so something like `.hidden { display: none; }` (maybe don't add this class to the first pill, if you need there to be something in the content box on load).

On the element that the user is going to click, you need to create some reference to the ID of the element in the content box that's going to be revealed. I like using `jQuery.data()` for this sort of thing, so on the clickable element, you'd add a data attribute and make a button like this: `</button class="pill-button" data-pill-id="<%= @pill.id %>">`.

Then for your jQuery click code, you'll want to hide all of the `.pill` elements, and then only show the matching one. So, something like this:

```
$('.pill-button').on('click', function() {
    $('.pill').addClass('hidden');
    $('#' + $(this).data('pillId')).removeClass('hidden');
});
```

Hope that gives you a decent starting place.